# The [dns] tag is a honeypot for bad questions

Tags: discussion, scope, tag-wiki, clean-up

While there certainly is intersection between DNS name lookup and programming, such as `gethostbyname()` function, it's sad that the entire first page of [dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dns) results are off-topic because they are OS configuration and/or hosted website configuration, using control panels written by others such that a solution using code is not even a possibility.

Probably part of the problem is a wikipedia-style tag summary, that doesn't remind askers that this site is only for programming questions.  Someone want to take a stab at providing that guidance?

Comment: The silence is deafening.........

Comment: Probably because we know that the people that post off-topic questions wouldn't read the tag description anyway.

Comment: Changed it to *“Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()”*

Comment: It is more likely that bad questions are a honey pot for the DNS tag :-)

Comment: StackOverflow's idea of what is on and off-topic should, in my experience, generally be ignored. You want technical experts? Go to SO, and just avoid moderator trolls.

Comment: @Stumbler: You will get more topic experts, and more favorable interactions with them, if you take the time to find out which site in the StackExchange network a question fits.  And while you may be quick to dismiss the rules, every one of them is there for multiple reasons.

Comment: And often *better* experts, too, @Stumbler.  Racing to provide an answer without paying attention to or caring whether a question is good or on-topic is more characteristic of the less experienced among us.

Comment: @BenVoigt Nonetheless, "Someone could ask for a recipe for a really tasty egg salad sandwich and probably get at least one answer before it could be closed." https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=497440#497440

Comment: @Jeutnarg And as that happens, both the questioner *and* asker will receive post bans.  Having the ability to ask a question is a privilege.  One that will be revoked when it's determined the user can't be trusted with it.  Same with answering.

Comment: @fbueckert: Do note that chat room wasn't for SO.  I think it was for EL&U where recipe questions wouldn't be tolerated either.  On Cooking SE, such a question might not ever be closed, depending on how it was phrased.  And on Super User, I would guess that this [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/149/) might be somewhat well received as an answer at least for the time it takes for the question to crash and burn.