# Why was the [google-domains] tag removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

In recent days, I have observed that hundreds of questions tagged [google-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-domains) were closed and deleted. Effectively, the tag is now gone. Why is that?

Answer (score 21):

The tag referred to a technology that is off-topic for Stack Overflow. All questions tagged [google-domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-domains) had nothing to do with programming and were more related to DNS setup or hosting a website.

Google offers an API, but questions asking for programmatic access to Google domains should be tagged with [google-domain-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-domain-api).

Related:

- [The [dns] tag is a honeypot for bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/362927/1839439)

Comment: I've tried to improve the [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34607716) and the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34607715) to match this answer and because it's going to be down soon.

Comment: @KevinM.Mansour When a tag is deleted due to no users, it loses its wiki information even when recreated, IIRC.

Comment: Note also that [Google is exiting the domains business](https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/squarespace-enters-definitive-agreement-to-acquire-google-domains-assets-301852507.html).

Comment: @kjhughes No, we do not need to note that Google is exiting the business. That has absolutely *zero* bearing on whether the subject is on-topic or not.

Comment: @nobody: I said nothing about anything being on- or off-topic.